# How to only draw points between concentric circles python / open cv

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am keen to only draw the points between the red circle and the green circle shown in figure . Filtering the results to only provide the necessary data

I am using sample code:-  https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d92/tutorial_corner_subpixels.html to detect the points

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import argparse
import random as rng
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

source_window = 'Image'

def goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo(val):
    # Parameters for Shi-Tomasi algorithm
    qualityLevel = 0.01
    minDistance = 10
    blockSize = 3
    useHarrisDetector = False
    k = 0.00004
    # Apply corner detection
    corners = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(src_gray, 48, qualityLevel, minDistance, None, \
        blockSize=blockSize, useHarrisDetector=useHarrisDetector, k=k)
    # Draw corners detected
    print('** Number of corners detected:', corners.shape[0])
   
    circle1 = cv.circle(src,(310, 184), 70, (0,255,0))
    circle2 = cv.circle(src,(310, 184), 82, (0,0,255))
    circle3 = cv.circle(src,(310, 184), 90, (255,0,0), 1)
 
    radius = 4
    for i in range(corners.shape[0]):
   
        cv.circle(src, (corners[i,0,0], corners[i,0,1]), radius, (rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256)), cv.FILLED)

    winSize = (5, 5)
    zeroZone = (-1, -1)
    criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TermCriteria_COUNT, 40, 0.001)
    # Calculate the refined corner locations
    corners = cv.cornerSubPix(src_gray, corners, winSize, zeroZone, criteria)
    for i in range(corners.shape[0]):
        print(" -- Refined Corner [", i, "]  (", corners[i,0,0], ",", corners[i,0,1], ")")
        #stringa = i #, corners[i,0,0], corners[i,0,1]
        #cv.putText(src,str(stringa), (corners[i,0,0], corners[i,0,1]), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 0, 0), 0)
       

    plt.imshow(src),plt.show(source_window)

# Load source image and convert it to gray

    src = cv.imread('/home/pi/Downloads/Top Artwork image.png')
    if src is None:
    print('Could not open or find the image:', args.input)
    exit(0)
    src_gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo(maxCorners)
    cv.waitKey()
```

[Output image showing detected points using the open cV good features to track method. Circles drawn to show where points need to be selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ08Y.png)